# changing datatype from varchar to cidr and macaddr

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres database. Tables are created and data is already imported into tables.
I want to change the datatype of several columns, ipv4, ipv6, mac  from varchar to cidr and macaddr, but I get an error. (these two columns sometimes have no value (NULL)).

> ERROR: invalid input syntax for type cidr: ""

This is my table.

```
CREATE TABLE "network" (
id int4 NOT NULL,
ipv4 cidr NULL,
ipv6 varchar NULL,  -> ERROR: invalid input syntax for type cidr: ""
"oldIpv4" varchar NULL,
"oldIpv6" varchar NULL,
mac varchar NULL
)
```

why can't I change datatype?

UPDATE:
I want to change the data type of ipv6, "oldIpv4", "oldIpv6" to cidr, but these column have already ' ' as values.
is it possible to change their datatype to cidr when they have ' ' as values. or should I stay with varchar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because:

```
select ''::cidr; 
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type cidr: "".
```

An empty string is not a valid value. To deal with do:

```
select nullif('', '')::cidr; 
NULL

select pg_typeof(nullif('', '')::cidr);
 pg_typeof 
-----------
 cidr
```

to change  the empty string to a `NULL`  `cidr` value.

**UPDATE**

To use one field(`"oldIpv4"`) to update the value of another field(`ipv4`):

```
create table cidr_test(id integer, ipv4 cidr, "oldIpv4" varchar);
insert into cidr_test values 
    (1, null, '192.168.100.128/25'), 
    (2, null, '10.1.2.3/32'), 
    (3, null, '');

select * from cidr_test ;
 id | ipv4 |      oldIpv4       
----+------+--------------------
  1 | NULL | 192.168.100.128/25
  2 | NULL | 10.1.2.3/32
  3 | NULL | 

begin ;
update cidr_test set ipv4 = nullif("oldIpv4", '')::cidr;

select * from cidr_test ;
 id |        ipv4        |      oldIpv4       
----+--------------------+--------------------
  1 | 192.168.100.128/25 | 192.168.100.128/25
  2 | 10.1.2.3/32        | 10.1.2.3/32
  3 | NULL               | 

commit;
```

**UPDATE #2**

Change column type in place:

```
truncate cidr_test ;

 \d cidr_test 
                   Table "public.cidr_test"
 Column  |       Type        | Collation | Nullable | Default 
---------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id      | integer           |           |          | 
 ipv4    | cidr              |           |          | 
 oldIpv4 | character varying |           |          | 


insert into cidr_test values 
    (1, null, '192.168.100.128/25'), 
    (2, null, '10.1.2.3/32'), 
    (3, null, '');

ALTER TABLE
    cidr_test 
ALTER COLUMN 
    "oldIpv4" TYPE cidr USING nullif("oldIpv4", '')::cidr;

\d cidr_test 
              Table "public.cidr_test"
 Column  |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
---------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 id      | integer |           |          | 
 ipv4    | cidr    |           |          | 
 oldIpv4 | cidr    |           |          | 

select * from cidr_test ;
 id | ipv4 |      oldIpv4       
----+------+--------------------
  1 | NULL | 192.168.100.128/25
  2 | NULL | 10.1.2.3/32
  3 | NULL | NULL
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I tried it.
I need to change the datatype in the defintion, how should use it in Alter Table.
is it possible to change it?

ALTER TABLE "network" ALTER COLUMN ipv4 TYPE cidr USING ipv4::cidr;

Comment: The column `ipv4` looks to already be type `cidr` from the definition in your question. Are you trying to move the values from `"oldIpv4"` to `ipv4`?

Comment: See my `UPDATE` for how to use `"oldIpv4"` to update values in `ipv4`.

Comment: Thank you again for the answer.
I dont want to move data from one coulmn to another. The datatype of "oldIpv4"is already defined as varchar, I want to change it to cidr.
data is already exist there and will be inserted everyday in to table. meaning everyday data will be added to the tables.

Comment: I think base on your explaination, it isnot possible to change datatype from varchar to cidr, if I have ' ' value in this column.

Comment: Then what is the purpose of the `ipv4 cidr NULL` column? That is the one you showed the error for. Update your question to show exactly what you want to do.

Comment: It is possible, you just need to be clear about what you want to achieve. Your comments in response to the answer differ from what you show in your question.

Comment: See **UPDATE #2**.

Comment: I updated.
usually we use ALTER TABLE "network" ALTER COLUMN ipv6 TYPE cidr USING ipv6::cidr; to chabnge datatype but I have ' ' values in ipv6, it gets error and I am not able to change it.
what is the command to change it to cidr if it has ' ' value.